# "Sport" as an informal appellation

Tags: word-usage, slang

I was watching a film ostensibly set during the American Progressive Era (1900 to 1918 or so), in which two teenaged boys used the line

> "Ah, be a sport, Charlie!"

That got me to thinking, was the term "sport" or "be a sport" in use in that way, that early? Around which time did the word "sport" become used to describe, as my dictionary puts it, behavior in a "good or specified way" in response to teasing or defeat?

What resources could I use to learn the answer to that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Ngram viewer shows that its use peaked "[in that way](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be%20a%20sport&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)" between 1919 and 1937. Here's an example from [1915](http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=JsIxAQAAMAAJ&q=%22be%20a%20sport%22&dq=%22be%20a%20sport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6Kr0UOanNsiNmQWi9oCQAg&redir_esc=y): "And pushed me to my fall. I was a young man, and the gay world called me to come. Gay women and gay men called to me. crying: 'Be a sport: lac a good sport! Fill our glasses and let us fill yours. We are young but once; let us dance and sing ...'"

The best source for early usages would be the *Oxford English Dictionary*.

Comment: Only a couple of decades earlier, to be a *sport* usually had very different connotations - [Munsey's Magazine, 1892](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3WlRAAAAYAAJ&q=%22he%27s+a+sport%22&dq=%22he%27s+a+sport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UcD0UOqiNsnM0AX424CYDw&redir_esc=y) *This man, Corwin, he ain't a gentleman. He's a sport an' a gambler an' a loafer.*